# Configuring webdav on sites root page

Tags: apache-http-server, webdav

So I'm trying to setup a small development apache server, where I can edit the live files through webdav, but I cannot figure out this directory stuff.

So the html files are located under /var/www/html but when I define this directory with Dav on, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /dav /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                DAV on
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```